# angular - How to create a canActivate guard to only allow redirects from another component?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-router-guards, canactivate

I have a component that I wish to allow it's access only in case of a redirect from another component.
So if I put the url in the browser it wouldn't allow me to access it but, if I redirect to it from another specific component like this it will be allowed:

```
this.router.navigate(['/main/myLockedComponent']);
```

I thought of adding a canActivate guard similar to an authGuard like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ValidationGuardService implements CanActivate{

  constructor() { }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean  {
    console.log(route);
    console.log(state);
    return true;
  }
}
```

but by printing state and route I can't find the information I need like **whether this component was redirected to internally from an angular component (and better yet from which component) or not**.

Edit: I am using angular 11.

Comment: is it ok if you get details from which route you are coming ? instead of the compenent ?

Comment: It's preferable if there is a way to get the component but for my case, if I can check if it's a redirect and get the route, I think it would suffice.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if you are redirected from a route like this [www.testsite.com/main/profile](http://www.testsite.com/main/profile) , you could write a condition inside your guard as

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ValidationGuardService implements CanActivate{

  constructor(private router : Router) { }
  canActivate(): boolean  {

    let currentUrl = this.router.url;
    let isFromProfile = currentUrl.indexOf('/profile') == -1 ? false : true;
    console.log(currentUrl);
    if(isFromProfile)
       return true;
    else 
       return false;
    }
}
```

You could also use the below method to check whether the last part of the url is the one we are expecting :

`let isFromProfile = this.router.url.split('/').pop() === 'profile';`

Hope this answered your question :-)

Comment: I have updated the answer . i wrongly added private router : Router inside canActivate earlier. Now added in constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but canActivate doesn't take a Router parameter and it throws an error "Property 'canActivate' in type 'ValidationGuardService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CanActivate'. Type '(router: Router) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<...>'..."

Comment: I have updated the answer . i wrongly added private router : Router inside canActivate earlier. Now added in constructor.